# Using Lax-Milgram for linear ODEs

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, bilinear-form

Consider an Sturm-Liouville deferential equation as:
$$Lu=(pu')'+qu$$
and differential equation as:
$$Lu+f=0$$
where $u(a)=u(b)=0$. We can convert the problem into a Lax-Milgram form for $f\in C[a,b]$ as follows:
$$B(u,\phi)=<f,\phi>,  \forall \phi \in C_c^\infty(a,b)$$
Assuming all the necessary conditions of Lax-Milgram theorem hold, I am wondering in which space the unique solution $u^*$ evolves?

In addition, for $f\in L_2[a,b]$, we can again construct a Lax-Milgram form as:
$$B(u,v)=F(v), \forall v\in H^1[a,b]$$
Again assume all necessary conditions hold, what is the space of solution?

Comment: We take $u,v\in H^1$ for the bilinear form to be well-defined with respect to the differential operator $L$.

Comment: @charlestoncrabb  Note that this does depend on the function $f$ and the space that $f$ belongs to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be the differential operator given by
$$Lu=(pu')'+qu$$
A weak solution of the Sturm–Liouville problem
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
Lu+f=0&\quad\text{on}\quad (a,b)\\
u(a)=u(b)=0&
\end{aligned}\right.\tag{1}$$
is a function $u^*\in H_0^1(a,b)$ such that
$$-\int_a^bp(u^*)'v'+\int_a^bqu^*v=-\int_a^bfv,\qquad\forall\ v\in H_0^1(a,b)$$

> **Theorem:** Assume $q\in C([a,b])$ and $p\in C^1([a,b])$ with $p(x)\leq \alpha<0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$.
>
> - If $f\in L_2(a,b)$, then the problem $(1)$ has an unique weak solution $u^*\in H_0^1(a,b)$. Furthermore, $u^*\in H^2(a,b)$.
> - If $f\in C([a,b])$, then the weak solution $u^*$ of $(1)$ belongs to $C^2([a,b])$ and in fact is a classical solution of $(1)$.

*Proof:* [Brezis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=brezis+partial+differential+sobolev&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjki7HknprcAhWutVkKHR4CDTcQuwUILTAA#v=onepage&q=brezis%20partial%20differential%20sobolev&f=false), pages 223-224.

**Remark:** In the proof we consider the bilinear form $B:H_0^1(a,b)\times H_0^1(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ and the functional linear $F:H_0^1(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$B(u,v)=-\int_a^bpu'v'+\int_a^bquv,\qquad F(v)=-\int_a^bfv$$